# Windows Workflow Persistence 4.5 Database Table Description

Tags: .net, sql-server, workflow-foundation-4

Where can I find the SQL Server Persistence Database table description for .NET 4.0 or 4.5? I can find the following:

[Workflow Tracking Service Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa347864%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

But this is specific to 3.5, and I know the structure has changed in .Net 4. I also found this document, but it only describes the views, not the tables created.

[Persistence Database Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In working with Microsoft Support I received this answer below, which is definitely not ideal, as it only really describes the views. I will update if I get a better response from them.

It looks like the database schema details is internal only and not available to public.
Only public documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943755(v=vs.110).aspx

Documentation on DB scripts is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlos/archive/2013/01/10/workflow-foundation-sql-scripts.aspx

Comment: I have spent far too long attempting to decipher the schema and details of the storage scheme to come to the conclusion that even if I understood the details it would not get me particularly far when attempting to debug or fix any issues.

 - It is possible to de-serialize the workflow state blob to XML but this won't get you very far as the data stored remains very cryptic.
 - Correlation data is stored in some manner comprised, at least in part, by serializing the data passed and the relative service path, hashing the result then converting to a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the files installed under

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en

I believe the files needed for WF4 are

> SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema.sql

and

> SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreLogic.sql

It isn't clear which are WF3 and which are WF4, but you can usually figure it out as WF4 table names are all `[System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[SomethingHere]`.  So if you're not sure about a file, crack it open and look for that namespace-style name.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the files. These show me the tables and columns, but it doesn't include a dictionary that describes the purpose of each column and table that I could tell.

Comment: @tlbignerd: Oooooooh, I misunderstood.  Yeah, I never found anything like that myself.  I consider them to be a black box into which I dare not look lest I be lost to sanity.  The documentation about durable instancing is very poor.  If you have a specific question, I'd track down members of the WF team at MS and ask them via email :/

Comment: Yeah, using my MSDN is the next step. StackOverflow is usually much faster :) I was surprised to find the information in 3.5, and hopeful for a 4.0 version, not sure why they only cover the views for the 4.0 version. Thanks.